# Either/both the properties are mandatory in JSON schema with the 3rd one

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have an object let's say,

```
payment
{
  "cash": { "$ref": "#/definitions/cash" },
  "point": { "$ref": "#/definitions/point" },
  "id": { "type": "string" }
}
```

Now, id is anyways mandatory, but cash and points can be either or both have values,
PS: anyone of them can be null as well.

> So I'll point out the cases that are possible
>
> - Cash and id is available, point is null
> - point and id is available, cash is null
> - all 3 are available

I'm trying to write a schema validator for a request payload

Comment: Could you show your full schema please? Is this what you have tried so far? I'm not totally clear if this is all you have tried so far.

Comment: @Relequestual So cash is an object, point is an object,
I have created the schemas respectively in definations.
now either of them can be null, or none of them can be null.

Comment: I’m still going to need to see the surrounding schema to know which solution is going to work for you.